# CSS background-size for list items using sprite sheet

Tags: html, css, hover, background-image, css-sprites

Please look at my snippet here:
http://jsfiddle.net/33fmA/

```
<div style="width:140px;border:1px solid blue;">
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>    
    <li>Item 2 with more text</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

i'm trying to css style a unordered list with a bullet image, the problem is that I can't set a fixed `background-image` `height` of `16px` in order to get proper hovering.
that's why for list items with more than one line the bullet image looks ugly.

is there a solution without having to add extra elements and floating/styling?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`:before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3abefore) pseudo here.. Now the issue with your solution is when you use sprites, you need an element to have fixed dimensions, using `background-size` will resize entire image, and NOT a particular part of the image.

So here, I create a virtual element using CSS `:before` pseudo, am assigning some fixed dimensions to that, also make sure that if you aren't using `position: absolute;` than make sure you declare `display: inline-block;` as `:before` pseudo generated content is *inline* by default.

```
li:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    top: 1px;
    background-image: /* Your base_64 junk */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/33fmA/1/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/33fmA/2/) *(Hover the last `li` for an active bullet state)*

Answer (score 0):

That's why we some times use a separate icon tag like

```
<span class="icon-cog"></span>
```

or

```
<i class="icon-bullet"></i>
```

So that you can give the icon the size you need.

Then you can have lots of configurations using background size and position.